# Задача по JS: Как сделать перебор возможных вариантов?

Tags: javascript

Candy weighs X grams, tangerine - Y grams and apple - Z grams.

Need to write a program that will determine how many different versions of gifts weighing exactly W grams can make Santa Claus.

Function should receive four integers X, Y, Z and W.

Function should return a single integer - the number of gift options.

```
X = 10
Y = 25
Z = 15
W = 40
Result: 3
```

вот что я смог сделать:

```
let candy = 10;
let tangerine = 25;
let apple = 15;
let weight = 40;
let num; // the number of gift options 
function Gifts(candy, tangerine, apple, weight) {
  if (candy + tangerine <= weight) {
    num = 1;
  }
  if (candy + apple <= weight) {
    num = 1;
  }
  if (tangerine + apple <= weight) {
    num = 1;
  }
  num = 1 + 1 + 1;
  console.log(num);
}
Gifts();
```

Comment: А как вы решали задачу и с какими проблемами столкнулись? Покажите ваш код

Comment: Ну я в JS'е буквально пару месяцев (в программировании в целом). Поэтому вот что я смог сделать, это 100% не правильно, но я пытался) ``` let candy = 10;
let tangerine = 25;
let apple = 15;

let weight = 40;

let num; //  the number of gift options

function Gifts(candy, tangerine, apple, weight) {
    if (candy + tangerine <= weight) {
        num = 1;
    }
    if (candy + apple <= weight) {
        num = 1;
    }
    if (tangerine + apple <= weight) {
        num = 1;
    }

    num = 1 + 1 + 1;
    console.log(num);
}

Gifts(); ```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос, пожалуйста, чтобы люди могли удобно посмотреть на код и ответить. В комментарии весьма неудобно. В редакторе есть добавить фрагмент кода, там можно добавить html/css/js который будет работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если веса большие, то достаточно перебрать количество каждого подарка.

```
function solve(x, y, z, w) {
    var result = 0
    for(var x_c = 0; x_c <= w / x; ++x_c) {
        for(var y_c = 0; y_c <= w / y; ++y_c) {
            for(var z_c = 0; z_c <= w / z; ++z_c){
                if(x_c * x + y_c * y + z_c * z == w) {
                    result++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Если веса не очень большие, то можно написать [рюкзак](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) с помощью динамики.

```
function solve(x, y, z, w) {
    let dp = new Array(w + 1).fill(0);
    dp[0] = 1;
    let p = [x, y, z];
    for(var k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        for(var i  = 1; i <= w; i++) {
            if(i >= p[k]) {
                dp[i] += dp[i - p[k]];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[w];
}
```